# Strong Parameters - Can't Access the Deeply-Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, strong-parameters

One StackOverflow question has asked what I need, but the self-answer didn't help me know what to do next. The scenario presented in that question ([whitelisting deeply nested strong parameters in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24171010/whitelisting-deeply-nested-strong-parameters-in-rails)) is pretty much what I've got going on, but I'll post an abbreviation of mine (still very long) and hope someone--maybe even the Dave of the post--can help (I don't have enough reputation to comment and ask him). There are few links about nested strong parameters I haven't read, and I've dealt with some on many controllers and API endpoints, but this is the most complex in the app. (I'm including such a long example so you can see the full complexity.)

This is on the `sales_controller`, and one of the attributes we can't get to is the `timezone_name`, which is in the `run_spans_attributes`, which is in the `options_attributes` under `sale`. I've tried just about all of the different syntax approaches that match most of the nested attributes with strong parameters issues here on StackOverflow, but none of it has worked. Do I need more classes? Are there magic brackets? I need new suggestions. Please.

It should be noted that this is with the strong_parameters gem and Rails 3.2.21, but I want to get the app ready for Rails 4, so I'm hoping to avoid a short-term solution.

Sorry it's so long:

```
 Parameters:
    "sale"=>{
      "cloned_from"=>"",
      "type"=>"Localsale",
      "primary_contact_attributes"=>{
          "primary"=>"true",
          "first_name"=>"Fred",
          "id"=>"1712"
        },
      "contract_signed_on"=>"March 20, 2015",
      "billing_addresses_attributes"=>{
          "0"=>{
              "billing"=>"1",
              "city"=>"San Diego",
              "id"=>"29076"
            }
        },
      "other_contacts_attributes"=>{
          "0"=>{
              "first_name"=>"Fred",
              "_destroy"=>"false",
              "id"=>"170914"
            },
          "1"=>{
              "first_name"=>"Fred",
              "last_name"=>"Smith",
              "_destroy"=>"false",
              "id"=>"1798"
            }
        },
      "opportunity_detail_attributes"=>{
          "original_salesperson_id"=>"",
          "id"=>"10130"
        },
      "production_editor"=>"1868097",
      "event_sale_attributes"=>{
          "0"=>{
              "name"=>"is_super_sale",
              "value"=>"0",
              "id"=>"15326"
            },
          "1"=>{
              "name"=>"super_show_code",
              "value"=>""
            },
        },
      "scheduling_note"=>"",
      "category_ids"=>["2", "364"],
      "options_attributes"=>{
          "0"=>{
              "title"=>"T-Shirt and Bag Check",
              "event_starts_at(1i)"=>"2015",
              "event_starts_at(2i)"=>"6",
              "event_doors_open_at_attributes"=>{
                  "option_id"=>"8682604",
                  "doors_time(1i)"=>"",
                  "id"=>"278382"
                },
              "event_option_attributes"=>{
                  "0"=>{
                      "name"=>"event_duration",
                      "value"=>""
                    },
                  "1"=>{
                      "name"=>"send_pre_event_email",
                      "value"=>"1",
                      "id"=>"632546"
                    }
                },
              "language_id"=>"1",
              "run_spans_attributes"=>{
                  "0"=>{
                      "timezone_name"=>"Eastern Time (US & Canada)",
                      "_destroy"=>"false",
                      "id"=>"560878"
                    },
                  "1429320288130"=>{
                      "timezone_name"=>"Eastern Time (US & Canada)",
                      "_destroy"=>"false"
                    }
                },
              "_destroy"=>"false",
              "id"=>"8682604"
              }#ends 0 option
          },#ends options
      "coupons_per_redemption"=>"1",
      "methods_attributes"=>{
          "0"=>{
              "redemption_code"=>"0",
              "_destroy"=>"0",
              "id"=>"9797012"
            },
          "1"=>{
              "redemption_code"=>"4",
              "_destroy"=>"1",
              "vendor_provided_promo_code"=>"0",
              "promo_code"=>""
            }
        }, #ends redemption methods
      "addresses_attributes"=>{
          "0"=>{
              "street_address_1"=>"2400 Cat St",
              "primary"=>"0",
              "id"=>"2931074",
              "_destroy"=>"false"
            }
        },
      "zoom"=>"",
      "video_attributes"=>{
          "youtube_id"=>"",
        },
      "updated_from"=>"edit"
      }
```

Help me do this right? By the way, all kinds of  `.tap do |whitelisted|` approaches have failed.

```
 private
 def_sale_strong_params
    params.require(:sale).permit(:how, :the, :heck, :do, :the_attributes =>
       [:make, themselves => [:known, :outside => [:of, :these => [:darn,
        :parentheses], :and], :brackets]])
 end
```

Comment: what are your failed trials? give one at least!

Comment: It would be great if you could trim down your example to the bit that is causing problems - if addresses_attributes or other_contacts_attributes (for example) are ok, then no need to include them in your post.

Comment: you are using arrays and giving it keys and values, you should try replacing arrays with hashes when they have sub values. like so `permit(:how, :the, :heck, :do, the_attributes: {:make, themselves: {:known, outside: {:of, these: [:darn, :parentheses], :and}, :brackets}})`, of course keys like `:of` and `:and` ideally would have values too

Comment: @caesarsol, the format I included at the bottom failed, as did the format @Mohammad AbuShady suggests. 

At one point, @Frederick, the code was not able to access some of the attributes even in the ```addresses_attributes``` or ```other_contracts_attributes```. I THINK I have managed to get them seen, but until the ```run_spans_attributes``` works, I won't know for sure. I thought it best to include them, just in case they're still an issue.

Answer (score 4):

**1. Validate Your Progress in the Console**

To configure Strong Parameters, it can help to work in the Rails console.  You can set your parameters into an `ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess` object and then start to test out what you'll get back from `ActionController::Parameters`.

For example, say we start with:

```
params = ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(
  "sale"=>{
    "cloned_from"=>"",
    "type"=>"Localsale"}
)
```

We can run this:

```
ActionController::Parameters.new(params).require(:sale).permit(:cloned_from, :type)
```

And we'll get this as the return value and we'll know we've successfully permitted `cloned_from` and `type`:

```
{"cloned_from"=>"", "type"=>"Localsale"}
```

You can keep working up until all parameters are accounted for.  If you include the entire set of parameters that you had in your question...

```
params = ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(
  "sale"=>{
    "cloned_from"=>"",
    "type"=>"Localsale",
    ...
    "options_attributes"=>{
      "0"=>{
        "title"=>"T-Shirt and Bag Check",
        ...
        "run_spans_attributes"=>{
          "0"=>{
            "timezone_name"=>"Eastern Time (US & Canada)",
            ...
)
```

...you can get down to `timezone_name` with a structure that will look something like this:

```
ActionController::Parameters.new(params).require(:sale).permit(:cloned_from, :type, options_attributes: [:title, run_spans_attributes: [:timezone_name]])
```

The return value in the console will be:

```
{"cloned_from"=>"", "type"=>"Localsale", "options_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"title"=>"T-Shirt and Bag Check", "run_spans_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"timezone_name"=>"Eastern Time (US & Canada)"}, "1429320288130"=>{"timezone_name"=>"Eastern Time (US & Canada)"}}}}}
```

**2. Break the Work Into Smaller Parts**

Trying to handle all of the allowed attributes for each model all on one line can get confusing.  You can break it up into several lines to make things easier to understand.  Start with this structure and fill in the additional attributes for each model:

```
video_attrs = []  # Fill in these empty arrays with the allowed parameters for each model
addresses_attrs = []
methods_attrs = []
run_spans_attrs = [:timezone_name]
event_option_attrs = []
options_attrs = [:title, event_option_attributes: event_option_attrs, run_spans_attributes: run_spans_attrs]
event_sale_attrs = []
opportunity_detail_attrs = []
other_contacts_attrs = []
billing_addresses_attrs = []
primary_contact_attrs = []
sales_attributes = [
  :cloned_from, 
  :type, 
  primary_contact_attributes: primary_contact_attrs, 
  billing_addresses_attributes: billing_addresses_attrs,
  other_contacts_attributes: other_contacts_attrs,
  options_attributes: options_attrs, 
  opportunity_detail_attributes: opportunity_detail_attrs,
  event_sale_attributes: event_sale_attrs,
  methods_attributes: methods_attrs,
  addresses_attributes: addresses_attrs,
  video_attributes: video_attrs
]
```

Then you can just send `*sales_attributes` into the permitted parameters.  You can verify in the console with:

```
ActionController::Parameters.new(params).require(:sale).permit(*sales_attributes)
```

Comment: That's a good idea. I'd used it a bit in console, but only to drill down once--starting directly from ```options_attributes```. Got that to work all the way to the ```:timezone_name```, but then it didn't work in practice (with the whole mess of them). Just a reminder to "keep working up" with all of them (slowly) in console is good advice. Thank you.

Comment: I've made an edit and added section #2 in my answer with a suggestion on how to organize this by breaking it down into several lines of code.

Comment: @wisetara section #2 is basically what I was saying when we chatted on Slack earlier.

Comment: @cschroed, I spent the evening setting it up as you suggested in your edit with high hopes. Took a bit to get the formatting right, which I was able to confirm with tests already established, and then...same error as I've had the last three days. It was a great suggestion, though, and the attributes are better organized. For now, I'm now looking into writing some better tests to help debug this problem, because it seems like something else is going on here. I'll update with more info when I have it.

Comment: Which attribute were you adding when you encountered the error and what was the error message?

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
params.require(:sale).permit(:options_attributes => [:other_attributes, { :run_spans_attributes => [:timezone_name] }]
```

Comment: I'm afraid that was the original scenario. It was so well organized, too! Since then, I've gotten rid of the braces, which seems to have helped (it can see ```:run_spans_attributes``` (if not the attributes themselves) without the braces there, whereas it couldn't before.

Answer (score 1):

Going by what I did in my controller, here's what I'd assume would work:

```
params.require(:sale).permit(:cloned_form, ... billing_addresses_attributes: [:id, :city, :building] ...)
```

Edfectively, put brackets around the attributes like "0"=> and don't forget to adf :id and :_destroy like I mentioned in my answer, as I ended up creating other models and used accepts_nested_attributes_for.

Comment: Thanks for this, Dave. I'm glad you saw the post! This is basically how I've started, unfortunately. Once I get something working, I'll post it. I've verified that the same hash is going through whether I use all-whitelisted strong params (which works in practice) or the specific list of whitelisted attributes (which does not work in practice), but it sure isn't being read the same. SOMEDAY, I hope.

Answer (score 1):

For posterity, I want to let folks know what we finally discovered: Well, the information was out there, and in fact, I read it in Russ Olsen's *Eloquent Ruby*, which I thankfully remembered during a debugging session with a more advanced developer: "With the advent of Ruby 1.9, however, hashes have become firmly ordered."

Why was that important? I'd alphabetized the attributes on the controller, and because of how the `run_span_attributes` were set up, they NEEDED `timezone_name` to be in the front. And if it wasn't, then it couldn't get to it. You can only imagine how debugging this tormented us. But at least we know now: ORDER MATTERS. So, if all else fails, remember that.

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, I found this problem only seemed to exist with hash keys that were integer strings.

When I replaced integers strings with non-integer strings, strong parameters accepted the hash.

Assuming we can't change the data format in our params, one workaround is to [allow arbitrary hashes](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit) at the level where you run into trouble (eg. :run_spans_attributes => {}).

If your form is used to modify a model, this open up the risk of mass assignment for the models you open up with the arbitrary hash -- you will want to keep that in mind.